# for i in {1..$VAR}; do echo $i; done

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm trying to do the following:

```
CPU_COUNT=$(cat /proc/stat | grep -E "^cpu[[:digit:]]+ " | wc -l)
let CPU_COUNT=CPU_COUNT-1
for core in {0..$CPU_COUNT}; do
 echo $core
done
```

On a system with 4 cores, I would expect the bash script to loop 4 times, incrementing core from 0 to 3.

The output I receive is however:

```
{0..3}
```

What I'm doing is clearly wrong, but how do I make it work as intended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `seq`.

```
for core in $(seq 0 $CPU_COUNT); do
```

**Edit**: You can use getconf(1) to get the number of CPU available:

```
CPU_COUNT=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 7):

[Bash is not parsed that way](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D); use

```
for ((i=0; i<CPU_COUNT; i++))
```

An additional advantage is the lack of a fork.

Comment: Thanks! But why the double parenthesis?

Comment: [Double parentheses](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) are the arithmetic evaluation markers.

Answer (score 5):

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are
>   either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment,
>   is an integer.

So bash doesn't support variables in sequence expressions. You can use a `for` loop instead:

```
for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this (*zsh*, *ksh93* and *bash* specific) syntax:

```
for ((core = 0; ++core <= ${CPU_COUNT:-0};)); do
 echo $core
done
```

You may also use *eval*, but that would be ugly.